# Is Magnus Carlsen ever going to play against Stockfish in a event?

Tags: engines, computer-chess

I was wondering if the actual champion is ever going to play against a chess engine like Kasparov and Krammik did?
Or is this kind of event not going to happen anymore due to the strength of the engines being just too high?

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it'll ever happen because:

- Who's going to pay? Deep Blue was covered by IBM, Deep Fritz was covered by Chessbase, but Stockfish is a free open-source engine.
- It's not fun for Carlsen to play an odd match with Stockfish, but he will likely be beaten convincingly if the match is fair.
- Human vs computer in chess is not interesting anymore. The focus has shifted to Go and Poker.

It's not going to happen.

Comment: Points 2 and 3 are valid, but point 1 isn't. *"Who's going to pay?"* - anyone who pays for any sort of event in the world: as well as you sponsor the Sinquefeld Cup, the Grand Prix or any other event, someone can sponsor a price money and claim the dividens out of it.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco if point 3 is valid nobody would spend the money and thus point 1 is correct as well

Comment: Incorrect: investors don't pay for events because they are "interesting": they pay for events so that they can sell their rights. Even if it isn't interesting anymore, Stockfish vs Carlsen would sell all around the world.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco if you are correct there would have been a match already..... I stand my point 1

Comment: *"if you are correct there would have been a match already."* false, exactly because the reason there has been no match isn't because of 1, rather it is because of 2.

Comment: We can argue forever. I encourage you to make a new answer for your points.

Answer (score 6):

This will not happen in a traditional form; engines are just too strong for that. In 2014, Nakamura, one of the world's top players, played a [match 'with odds'](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chess.pl?tid=84631) against Stockfish. In two of those games, Stockfish was a pawn down; in the other two games, Nakamura had the help of an older version of the engine running on a slower computer. Stockfish won both minimatches with 1.5 - 0.5.

Answer (score 6):

Although it would be very exciting, I don't believe it would ever happen. Here is a quote out of the mouth of Magnus:

> *Would you participate in a public game against a computer in the near future - or is that not an option for you? The last one I remember was
>   Vladimir Kramnik against Deep Fritz in 2006.*
>
> I personally never wanted that. I find it much more interesting to
>   play humans. And also, of course, now that they have become so strong
>   in a game like that, I wouldn't stand a chance.

http://www.dw.com/en/world-chess-champion-magnus-carlsen-the-computer-never-has-been-an-opponent/a-19186058

From watching Magnus Carlsen many years shows that his style of play is not suited to playing against a computer. His desire to win causes him to willfully play weaker or obscure moves to confuse/challenge his opponents; this will surely mean he will be a lamb to the slaughter against a modern day computer chess software.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure Magnus would not like to compete in an event like that because it is not a new kind of Event anymore which would arouse any innovative interest for the Chess World . As for Strength true the Engines have a relatively higher rated but I confide in Magnus more because I have seen some of his amazing games which are full of Innovative ideas which even Kasparov & Fischer would have not been able to do .